# Sources on adultery for a man

Tags: sources-mekorot, men-male, arayot

I haven't heard much discussion on adultery for a man. It seems the focus is on adultery of a woman, since she can't have more than one husband. A man however can have more than one wife. As well, there's the death penalty for a woman who has relations with someone other than her husband, but not for a husband who has relations with someone other than his wife.

At the same time, I recently saw the following Tosafos, which very much affirms that there's a concept of adultery for a man.

The context is the opinion of Rabbi Elazar (who we don't rule like), who says any extramarrital relations makes the woman a *zonah*. [Tosafos](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.61b.14?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Yevamot.61b.14) comments:

> לאו דוקא נקט פנוי דכ"ש נשוי שמזנה על אשתו דחשובה זונה:
>
> He's not specifically referring to a single man, as all the more so if he's married and he cheats on his wife, that this woman would become a *zonah*.

We see at least the concept exists and it's considered worse in some ways than a single guy with a single girl. I was therefore wondering: are there any other sources which discuss adultery for a man? Preferably Rishonim.

Comment: Marrying a second wife itself without consent from the first wife is grounds for divorce (Yevamos 65a). Marrying a second wife in a country where polygamy is not allowed is also assur (Shulchan Aruch EH 1:9). These are even if he can easily support them both. So for sure adultery is a problem.

Comment: The medrash of the weasel and the pit implies bilateral value to monogamy. See e.g. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8